# view error Rebol 3

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I'm trying to add a gui to my program but have difficulties doing so.

```
>> system/version
== 3.0.0.4.40
```

Downloaded from http://atronixengineering.com/downloads.html

First, where can I find examples and documentation for the `guie` of my interpreter version?

There is some [documentation](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/gui/guide.html), but it doesn't work.

```
REBOL []
do %./r3-gui.r3

view [
    title "Simple Form"
    panel 2 [
        label "Name:"
        field
        label "Message:"
        area
    ]
    button "Cancel" close
]
```

The error message:

```
** GUI ERROR: Cannot parse the GUI dialect at: panel 2 [
    label "Name:"
    field
    label "Message:"
    area
]
button "Cancel"
```

Edit: `panel 2` returns an error.  If I remove it, there's another error with `button`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the development release. This is working.

```
load-gui 
view [
  title "Simple Form"
  vpanel  [
    label "Name:"
    field
    label "Message:"
    area
  ] options [box-model: 'frame]
  button "Cancel" on-action [close-window face]
]
```

There is a [demo application](http://www.atronixengineering.com/r3/demo.r), you can start with demo, that serves as an example.

The documentation you mention refers to the implementation of Carl S. which is different from the atronix and saphirion version.